# jQuery: How to know the div id value?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with youtube results as

```
  <div id="result" style="display: block;">

    <div id="lqT_dPApj9U" class="item view-item">
      <div style="float: left;"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src=
      "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/m0SdBmkp9cw/default.jpg" /></div>

      <div id="name">
        <p class="title">Title goes here</p>

        <p class="views">2192501</p>
      </div><input id="video_id" type="hidden" />
    </div>

    <div id="hKoB0MHVBvM" class="item view-item">
      <div style="float: left;"><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src=
      "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lqT_dPApj9U/default.jpg" /></div>

      <div id="name">
        <p class="title">Coca-Cola Happiness Machine</p>

        <p class="views">4791156</p>
      </div><input id="video_id" type="hidden" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Question

How can I get the value of div id="hKoB0MHVBvM" from result div?

I tried the following jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.item').live('click', function(){
        alert($(this).id);
    });
});​
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `id` is an html attribute, but `$(...)` is a jQuery object. You can either simply reference the id of the element itself (`this.id` -- right way!), or use the jQuery method for retrieving attributes (`$(this).attr("id")` -- overkill)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.item').live('click', function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});​
```

`this.id` is 'native' and faster than the jQuery `$(this).attr('id');` (slow and verbose).

P.S: From jQuery 1.6 `.live()` method is deprecated. If you have an updated version use rather `.on()` like:

`$('#result').on('click', '.item', function(){`

http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: @daydreamer `.on()` is cool, if you have dynamically generated elements you can bind the event handler directly to them like: `$('#result').on('click', '.item', function(){` -> that's the 'modern' version of `.live()`

Comment: I tried this but doesn't seem to work on my system, even though I am using jQuery 1.7.2 :(

Comment: @daydreamer (what exactly?) Please setup a http://jsfiddle.net so I can take a look.

Comment: @daydreamer sure it works http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/CkgM5/ . Drop me a link to the site in question.

Comment: I create a list of results and append them to div, where do I need to add this handler?, when I add this while appending, click results in alert popups, check the same fiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12971/discussion-between-roko-c-buljan-and-daydreamer)

Answer (score 2):

the attr method is what you need:

```
$(function(){
    $('.item').live('click', function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: Two things: `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 (and `delegate()` recommended in earlier versions); also why use a jQuery object to retrieve the `id`, just use `this.id` (it's a little cheaper and faster).

Comment: Yup, `this.id` is better for this case.... but if you didn't know about the `attr()` method and you're using jquery it's good to get familiar with it;)